# What is the equivalent to "OnBackKeyPress"

Tags: windows-runtime, back, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

In Windows Phone 8.0 I used this to handle the back button:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnBackKeyPress(e);        
}
```

This Event does not exists on the "Page" control. How can I handle a click on the back button in WP 8.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.ui.input.hardwarebuttons.aspx).

If you add a Basic Page to your project then VS will add a NavigationHelper class to your project which helps with Navigating thru your App, you can also see in the source code that it is subscribing to `Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed`.

---

In case you want to extend handling the Back Button (managing Eventhandler queue and so on) you may take a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23356169/2681948) - the method there will help to prevent backward navigation (if you don't need it) and add some more behaviours.

Comment: Does it matter that the documentation states "This API is supported in native apps only"

Comment: @Roman I've added a link to other answer which you may be interested in - helps to handle the BackButton, prevent navigation and more.

Comment: @LukkhaCoder You won't be able to use it with Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight.

Comment: @Nanoc That's right, MSDN also says that. The question was about WP8.1 Runtime.

Comment: Great tip, it can still be used in shared code when you surround the event wire up with a #if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP compiler statement

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.ui.input.hardwarebuttons.aspx) like above comment. But this event always is throwed in every page. So you can use like below example and this only is throwed in active page.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
}

void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
    // Navigate to a page
}
```

I solve my problem with this way.

Comment: This worked for me in a universal app. I needed, however to nest it inside the #if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP statements.

Comment: Shouldn't the HardwareButtons_BackPressed event be removed on OnNavigatedFrom ?

Comment: Why shouldn't? If u dont remove and add new event to it on new page, the two events are triggered when u press back button.

Answer (score 1):

Im migrating my wp8 proyect to wp8.1 universal, so to not touch too much my code I do:

In my page base class, in the constructor, I added:

```
 public VBasePage()
    {
        Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
    }
```

And then:

```
private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        var args = new CancelEventArgs();
        OnBackKeyPress(args);
        if (args.Cancel)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
protected virtual void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

So I can use my current overrides for OnBackKeyPress method