# How can i override back button as I used to?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I've just installed Windows Phone 8.1 SDK, and had an application in mind. But I cant even navigate back and forth! Back button the phone exit the application by default, and since all the pages now inherits "Page" the override for the back button isnt exposed.

Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn639128.aspx but I don't understand it, how can I implement it?

Comment: You may also have a look at [this extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23356169/2681948) - maybe will help a little with managing events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at any of the WP Projects that are included with Visual Studio (eg: The Hub App project). Or add a new "BasicPage" to your application. You will notice that they are using a NAvigationHelper to subscribe to the BackPressed event for you already. The post you linked to explains it pretty well.

> The most important thing to know about the BackPressed event that is raised when the user presses the back button is that if your app **does not handle the event, by setting BackPressedEventArgs.Handled property to true, the operating system will suspend your app** and return the user to the previous experience

The example is given in that post

```
private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    if (frame == null)
    {
       return;
    }

    if (frame.CanGoBack)
    {
        frame.GoBack();
        e.Handled = true;
   }
```

}

Notice it sets `e.Handled = true;` to indicate that the app should not "close". You are saying "Hey, I've got this handled already". In the example, it will navigate to the previous page.

Comment: I guess I'm not ready for the new age :P But whats up with this new project type AND keeping the old silverlight one?

Comment: WP apps will be moving to the new Runtime, but all functionality is not moved over yet. So if you need some things, or just don't want to create a Runtime app, use a Silverlight one. Soon everything will be Runtime based.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Shawn! "Runtime app" is the new lingo?