# Windows phone 8.1 handle back button on data entry page

Tags: mvvm, back-button, windows-phone-8.1, data-entry

I have an screen in my app where a user enters data. When they leave the page the entered data is not saved, how can I implement a confirmation mechanism if the user has not saved the data. I am using MVVM as a design pattern.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider two things:

- first - the User leaves your *Page* with <kbd>Back Button</kbd> - he wants to navigate back or exit the App - in this case you should show some kind of prompt with *Save/No* buttons. You must do it before `Frame.GoBack()` executes - depending on where you navigation back is performed (App.xaml.cs, NavigationHelper, other), you will have to nadle it differentially. The main idea is to invoke your eventhandler with prompt, before the one with navigation, and set `e.Handeled = true` (you will also have to ensure that the eventhandler with navigation check if `e.Handeled != true`). As for subscribing before any other eventhandlers, you may [have a look at this code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23356169/2681948)
- second - the User leaves your *Page* with <kbd>Start/Search/Hold Back</kbd> buttons - in this way your App will be [*Suspended*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464925.aspx) and you cannot stop it. What you can do in this situation - subscribe to the [Suspending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.application.suspending.aspx) event and save the state of what user has entered, then bring it back on [Resuming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.application.resuming.aspx) event.