# Windows phone 8.1 BackPressed not working properly

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Windows phone 8.1 new to world. Basic function is back button click. Is that function not working properly is this windows phone 8.1. Is that behavior or i'm made mistake.

Below code using in Homepage but this code calling from all other class too while clicking back. I need to access below method only on Home page .

Please check below code and refer me good solution.

**Please look my code:**

```
 public HomePage()
 {
  this.InitializeComponent(); 
  Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
 }

    void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is working properly. The [BackPressed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn639128.aspx) is working app-wide. Two options that come to my mind:

- write eventhandler that would recognize the *Page* in which you currently invoke it - simple example can look like this:

  ```
  private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
  {
      Frame frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
      if (frame == null) return;

      if (frame.Content is HomePage)
      {
          e.Handled = true;
          Debug.WriteLine("I'm in HomePage");
      }
      else if (frame.CanGoBack)
      {
          frame.GoBack();
          e.Handled = true;
      }
  }
  ```
- second option - subscribe to `Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed` when you enter the *Page* and unsubscribe when you leave the *Page*. Note that in this way there are some pitfalls - you have to handle properly OnNavigatedTo, OnNavigatedFrom, Suspending and Resuming (more about [Lifecycle here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464925.aspx)). Note also that the subscription should be done before others - for example *NavigationHelper*.

Some remarks - the above code should work, but it also depends on other circumstances:

- if there is something other subscribed to `BackPressed` before (in App.xaml.cs) - remember that usually events are fired in order they were subscribed
- check if you are using NavigationHelper - it also subscribes to `BackPressed`
- remember not to subscribe multiple times
- remember to allow the User to leave your HomePage

Comment: @Jeeva123 You are welcome. You may take a look [at this code snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23356169/2681948) if you need to add haldlers to the top or play with BackPressed. Maybe it will help.