# HardwareButton BackPressed Doesnt Work properly in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have written this code for hardware back button,but it doesnt work properly.
1.first time wen i press back( e.g. from page3) it works fine(it redirect to page 2) bt again wen i go to to my next page(page3) and again press back but it doesnt work..it directoly goes to home page or main page(page1)..can anyone having solution for this to go to on page2 from page3, doesnt matter how many times u redirect from that page..please..thanks

```
HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;

void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            if (rootFrame == null)
            return;
            if(rootFrame.CanGoBack)
            {
                rootFrame.GoBack();
                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are preventing back key press by this :

```
e.Handled = true;
```

Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111527/what-is-the-equivalent-to-onbackkeypress).It will clear your ideas.

Comment: void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(Object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {
          e.Handled = true;
            Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(EditProfileAccount));
        
        }

Comment: this code works,but now how can u save state of data or how can u restore data of prev page...in my case wen i navigated to page2 from page3 the data on page2 get lost but i dont want that,i need to be page just get navigated and data should not be lost...how to do??if anyone knows please tell me..thank you

Comment: you must save your data at layer above UI in your project,so that you can use them anywhere.

Comment: i m not getting u,can u please explain how?

Comment: Your data should be independent of UI.Suppose, you are binding ListBox with ObservableCollection,then keep ObservableCollection static and in Model class above the UI layer.So that you can access it anywhere.So although you lose UI page you can access your data.